# Show reference variable in glm model in R?

Tags: r, glm, lm, summary, dummy-variable

Is there a way to show the reference variable of a glm model in R?

Imagine a linear regression model with a dependent variable, `y`, and one explanatory categorical variable, `x1`, with three levels, dummified as `x1_0`, `x1_1`, and `x1_2`:

```
model <- glm(y ~
               # x1_0 reference variable
                 x1_1
               + x1_2
               , data = data
               , family = "binomial")
```

The standard output for this, `summary(model)`, would look something like this:

```
Coefficients:
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                           -1.53397    0.59985  -2.557 0.010551 *  
x1_1                                   0.67132    0.19262   3.485 0.000492 ***
x1_2                                   0.34110    0.11995   2.844 0.004460 **
```

Is there a way to make the output look more like this?:

```
Coefficients:
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                           -1.53397    0.59985  -2.557 0.010551 *  
x1_0                                   
x1_1                                   0.67132    0.19262   3.485 0.000492 ***
x1_2                                   0.34110    0.11995   2.844 0.004460 **
```

To be clear, I am not asking for the `+0` or `-1` trick, because I do not want either to interpret the reference dummy or substitute the intercept. All I want is some way to include the reference dummy somewhere in the output so that I can avoid manually adding rows later to clarify what level of the categorical variable was used as the reference.

Any ideas? If I missed a question already answered, please redirect me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want exactly the output you showed, you have no choice but to edit the output.

You can get close by editing the summary object.  I'm not sure if you'd find this preferable to editing the output, though:

```r
data <- data.frame(y = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                   x = factor(sample(letters[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE)))
fit <- glm(y ~ x, data = data, family = "binomial")
summ <- summary(fit)
summ$coefficients <- rbind(summ$coefficients["(Intercept)",,drop=FALSE], 
                           xa = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                           summ$coefficients[c("xb", "xc"),])
summ
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = y ~ x, family = "binomial", data = data)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -1.2949  -1.2933  -0.9005   1.0658   1.4823  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
#> (Intercept)  -0.6931     0.3693  -1.877   0.0605 .
#> xa                NA         NA      NA       NA  
#> xb            0.9651     0.4965   1.944   0.0519 .
#> xc            0.9614     0.5216   1.843   0.0653 .
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 138.59  on 99  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 133.68  on 97  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 139.68
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>